# Flutter's GetIt with the app in background

Tags: flutter

I'm having issues with using GetIt while the app is in background. With the app is in focus everything works great but the moment I switch focus everything breaks. What's my error here?

I'm using GetIt 6.1.1, flutter 2.0.5, here's the stacktrace

```
I/flutter ( 5125): FlutterFire Messaging: An error occurred in your background messaging handler:
I/flutter ( 5125): 'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart': Failed assertion: line 315 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null': Object/factory with  type NotificationCubit is not registered inside GetIt. 
I/flutter ( 5125): (Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
I/flutter ( 5125): Did you forget to register it?)
```

Here's my GetIt setup

get_it.dart

```dart
GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

void setupGetIt() {
  getIt.registerSingleton<NotificationCubit>(NotificationCubit());
}
```

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  // some other methods
  setupGetIt();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And the method that throws the error.

```
void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
  getIt
      .get<NotificationCubit>()
      .addNotification(NotificationClassName.fromRemoteMessage(message));

  _displaySnackBar(message);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `setupGetIt();` again in your `_handleMessage`, the code becomes:

```
void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
   
   //Add it here
   setupGetIt();
   getIt
    .get<NotificationCubit>()
    .addNotification(NotificationClassName.fromRemoteMessage(message));

  _displaySnackBar(message);
 }
```

The error is thrown because when `_handleMessage` method is called, the compiler fails to find `getIt.registerSingleton<NotificationCubit>(NotificationCubit());` which registers `NotificationCubit>`.

Comment: That worked for me but had another problem - the instances were different when I checked it in the debugger. This all happens in backgroundMessage handler if that was not clear. I had the same issue with SharedPreferences for example, did you happen to encounter that?

Comment: Try to init SharedPreferences before setupGetIt() in the background handler, and then let me know.

Comment: Well, how would I do that? SharedPreferences are not supposed to be initialized as far as I know. An example could be better. I open the app and save a value to key 'notifications', after getting the prefs in the background handler the value is no longer there, as is there are two instances of SharedPreferences, one in the main app and one for the background process.